# Code seems to stop right after .responseXML. xmlDoc is null

Tags: javascript, html, xml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<script>
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","docu.xml",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
    { 

        // This is where my alert indicates that xmlDoc = null
        // then nothing else happens below.

        document.getElementById("stuff")=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("details")
        [0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    }
</script>
<input type="text" name="stuff" id="stuff"/>
</body>
</html>
```

BELOW IS THE DOCU.XML STORED ON THE ROOT DIRECTORY

```
<?xml=version '1.0'?>
<root>
<details>xml data does not appear</details>
</root>
```

Comment: Please format your post properly. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: while i was editing this, i wasn't sure if you really wanted to have `[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);` in a new line and why there is a closing bracket at the end... maybe that's the issue...?